# Show that $1+\cos(\theta)+\cos(2\theta)+\cos(3\theta)+\cos(4\theta)+\cos(5\theta)+\cos(6\theta) = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

Let $\theta=2\pi/7$, show that $1+\cos(\theta)+\cos(2\theta)+\cos(3\theta)+\cos(4\theta)+\cos(5\theta)+\cos(6\theta) = 0$

I have found that $\cos(4\theta) = \cos(8\pi/7) = \cos(6\pi/7) = \cos(\theta)$ and,
similarly, $\cos(5\theta) = \cos(2\theta)$ and $\cos(6\theta) = \cos(\theta)$.Thus the expression
$$1+\cos(\theta)+\cos(2\theta)+\cos(3\theta)+\cos(4\theta)+\cos(5\theta)+\cos(6\theta) = 0$$
can be written as

$$1+2\cos(\theta)+2\cos(2\theta)+2\cos(3\theta)= 0$$

Where do I get that $\cos(\theta)$ satisfies the polynomial $8x^3+4x^2-4x-1$.

But at the moment I don't see how it can help me with what I need. Is it the correct way? If not, could you give me a hint of where to go?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use the property that $\cos(x) = Re(e^{i x})$, where $Re(z)$ is the real part of $z$, then:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^6 \cos(k\theta)
&= Re\left(\sum_{k=0}^6 e^{ik\theta}\right) \\
&= Re\left(\frac{1-e^{i7\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}\right) \\
&= Re\left(\frac{1-e^{i2\pi}}{1-e^{i\frac{2\pi}{7}}}\right) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
as $e^{i2\pi} = 1$.